# android ArrayAdapter items update

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have ArrayAdapter with this items structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout ... >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
             ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add this adapter so:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, 
                                            R.id.itemTextView, itemsText);
```

All is fine but I want to update text in adapter's items. I found a solution

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but do not understand how to use it. Help please.

**upd**
My code:

```
String[] itemsText = {"123", "345", "567"};
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
```

onCreate

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.roomitem, 
                                              R.id.itemTextView, itemsText);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
itemsText = {"789", "910", "1011"};
```

onClick

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//it's dont work
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think something like this

```
public void updatedData(List itemsArrayList) {

    mAdapter.clear(); 

    if (itemsArrayList != null){

        for (Object object : itemsArrayList) {

            mAdapter.insert(object, mAdapter.getCount());
        }
    }

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: You don't need to add items to the adapter, just call notifyDataSetChanged once you've finished work on the arraylist

Comment: I call notifyDataSetChanged but nothing happens

Comment: what do you do in the onClick, or the method where u change something in the itemsText?

Comment: Doing this will cause all items in your list to flicker every time there's a change, and the list view will scroll back to the top every time.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 40):

Your problem is a typical Java error with pointers.

In a first step you are creating an array and passing this array to the adapter.

In the second step you are creating a new array (so new pointer is created) with new information but the adapter is still pointing to the original array.

```
// init itemsText var and pass to the adapter
String[] itemsText = {"123", "345", "567"};
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(..., itemsText);

//ERROR HERE: itemsText variable will point to a new array instance
itemsText = {"789", "910", "1011"};
```

So, you can do two things, one, update the array contents instead of creating a new one:

```
//This will work for your example
items[0]="123";
items[1]="345";
items[2]="567";
```

... or what I would do, use a List, something like:

```
List<String> items= new ArrayList<String>(3);
boundedDevices.add("123");
boundedDevices.add("456");
boundedDevices.add("789");
```

And in the update:

```
boundedDevices.set("789");
boundedDevices.set("910");
boundedDevices.set("1011");
```

To add more information, in a real application normally you update the contents of the list adapter with information from a service or content provider, so normally to update the items you would do something like:

```
//clear the actual results
items.clear()

//add the results coming from a service
items.addAll(serviceResults);
```

With this you will clear the old results and load the new ones (think that the new results should have a different number of items).

And off course after update the data the call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`;

If you have any doubt don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: I am using fragments.I did all of the above steps.But,I my arrayadapter is not updating.Any advice

Comment: Put some example please.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming itemTexts as String array or String ArrayList,where you are adding new items into itemsTextat that time after that you can call

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you did not get answer then please put some code.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. And it works correctly.

Add method to the Adapter class:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<ITEM> itemList){
        this.itemList.clear();
        this.adapterList = new ArrayList<ITEM>();
        this.adapterList .addAll(itemList);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Call the method in the class you use the adapter:

```
itemList.add(item);
adapter.updateList(itemList);
```