# ListView text changing but not adapter data

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I added 3 items to my `ListView`. Each item says "Test". When I click on an item, I clear that item's text. However, when I check the variable in the "watches" log, the item is still named "Test" even though I removed the text.

watches log:

```
adapter2.getItem(1) = {java.lang.String@830045070536}"Test"
list.getItemAtPosition(1) = {java.lang.String@830045070536}"Test"
```

I want the `ListView` to get updated and make the item blank after being clicked

for example the watches log should look like this:

```
adapter2.getItem(1) = {java.lang.String@830045070536}""
list.getItemAtPosition(1) = {java.lang.String@830045070536}""
```

Can some one please tell me why my this is happening and offer a solution?

**Edited Code**

```
public class ListView2 extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    List<String> array_list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview2, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        array_list.add("Test");
        array_list.add("Test");
        array_list.add("Test");

        //Build Adapter
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.items, array_list);

        //Configure the list view
        list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        list.setAdapter(adapter2);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                TextView txt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                if(txt.getText().toString().equals("Test")) {
                    txt.setText("");
                }else{
                    txt.setText("Test");
                }
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: call adapter.notifyDatasetchanged() when you update the text

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. When I call  adapter.notifyDatasetchanged() nothing happens when I click. "Test" never disappears

Comment: you are adding text as  adapter2.add("Test"); update the text at the clicked position and then call adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380662/android-arrayadapter-items-update ?

Comment: check out my new code. it still does not work

Comment: @user2456977 If you are updated your code once see my setOnItemClickListener code clearly you are not replacing items in ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to update TextView directly is not the good way. You can do it by using remove() and insert() methods to update your ArrayAdapter. For a reference, please check it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29) ,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if(adapter2.getItem(position).equals("Test")) {
                adapter2.remove("Test");
                adapter2.insert("", position);
            }else{
                adapter2.remove("");
                adapter2.insert("Test", position);
            }
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

This is another way to update ArrayAdapter without removing and inserting entry to same position as you mention in comment.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
        if(arrayList.get(position).equals("Test")) {
            arrayList.set(position, "");
        }else{
            arrayList.set(position, "Test");
        }
        adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: thanks this works great. It would be nice if there was a more direct way to update the listview without deleting the entry and adding a new entry in the same position

Answer (score 0):

On the item click listner you must be getting the view of the row, use that row object and find the view in that row i.e a textview in your case. Set the text of that view to be blank and also change the data set item on that position so that view and data are in sync. In this way there is no need to update the whole list and saves the time.

If any of the above point is not clear please mention.