# Java stack not working with Android adapter

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

I'm developing a file manager app for Amazon S3 in Android. I'm using a stack to hold folder objects to help navigation. Each object in the stack is a folder which holds an arraylist `mObjects` of the files and folders in that folder.

An onClick event listener pushes the previously clicked object onto the stack and calls a setter for the arraylist for the clicked object.

The problem is that subsequent objects pushed onto the stack change the `mObjects` field of the very first object in the stack. I don't understand why because the `mObjects` field has modifier private for each object.

Many hours of code staring and Google searches have turned up a blank. I've done a stack trace in Android Studio and what I find weird is that the `mObjects` field for the first object on the stack changes at the line `adapter.setData(o.getmObjects())` in my BucketObjectListFragment class.

```
public class BucketObjectListFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static List<S3ObjectSummary> s3ObjList;
    private final int position = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        generateS3Objects();
        for(S3ObjectSummary s : s3ObjList) {
            Log.i("s3ObjList", s.getKey());
        }

        //Create the stack
        ObjectStack myStack = new ObjectStack();

        //Create a new object to hold the home list view
        BucketObject o = new BucketObject();
        o.setPrefixKey("/");

        //Create the home object's list of folders and files
        o.setHomeObjects();

        //Create an adapter to hold the list of files and folders
        ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter(o.getmObjects());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //Replicate an Android onClick event. First push the home view onto the stack.
        myStack.push(o);
        Log.i("Stack dump", "...");
        myStack.printStack();

        //Create a new BucketObject for the clicked folder.
        o = ((ObjectAdapter) getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        o.setmObjects(o.getPrefixKey());
        adapter.setData(o.getmObjects());

        myStack.push(o);
        Log.i("Stack dump", "...");
        myStack.printStack();
    }

    public static void generateS3Objects(){
        //Generate a random list of files and directories that look like S3 objects.
        S3ObjList = new ArrayList<S3ObjectSummary>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            S3ObjectSummary obj = new S3ObjectSummary();
            s3ObjList.add(obj);
        }
    }

    private class ObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BucketObject> {
        private ObjectAdapter(ArrayList<BucketObject> objects) {
            super(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<BucketObject> items) {
            clear();
            setNotifyOnChange(false);
            if (items != null) {
                for (BucketObject item : items)
                    add(item);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

My BucketObject class.

```
public class BucketObject {
    private UUID id;
    private String prefixKey;
    private String key;
    private ArrayList<BucketObject> mObjects;

    public BucketObject() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public BucketObject(String mPrefixKey, String mKey) {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
        prefixKey = mPrefixKey;
        key = mKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return prefixKey;
    }

    public String getPrefixKey() {
        return prefixKey;
    }

    public void setPrefixKey(String mPrefixKey) {
        prefixKey = mPrefixKey;
    }

    public ArrayList<BucketObject> getmObjects(){
        return mObjects;
    }

    public ArrayList<BucketObject> setHomeObjects(){
        ArrayList<BucketObject> mFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        mObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        //Use a HashSet to hold unique folders and directories
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();

        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : BucketObjectListFragment.s3ObjList) {
            String obj = summary.getKey();
            int firstSlash = obj.indexOf("/");

            if (firstSlash != -1){ //if object has multiple forward slashes
                String myKey = obj.substring(0, firstSlash);
                if(mySet.add(myKey)){ //add to set if not a duplicate directory
                    BucketObject b = new BucketObject((myKey + "/"), myKey);
                    mObjects.add(b);
                }
            }
            else {
                //Get files
                BucketObject b = new BucketObject(obj, obj);
                mFiles.add(b);
            }
        }
        mObjects.addAll(mFiles);
        return mObjects;
    }

    public ArrayList<BucketObject> setmObjects(String prefixKey){
        ArrayList<BucketObject> mFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        mObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        //Use a HashSet to hold unique folders and directories
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();

        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : BucketObjectListFragment.s3ObjList) {
            String obj = summary.getKey();
            if (obj.startsWith(prefixKey)) {
                String suffix = obj.replaceFirst(prefixKey, "");
                int firstSlash = suffix.indexOf("/");

                if (firstSlash != -1) {
                    String key = suffix.substring(0, firstSlash);
                    if (mySet.add(key)) { //add to set if not a duplicate directory
                        BucketObject b = new BucketObject(obj, key);
                        mObjects.add(b);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(!suffix.equals("")) {
                        BucketObject b = new BucketObject(obj, suffix);
                        mFiles.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mObjects.addAll(mFiles);
        return mObjects;
    }
}
```

My ObjectStack class.

```
public class ObjectStack {
    private Stack<BucketObject> s3ObjectStack;

    public ObjectStack(){
        s3ObjectStack = new Stack<>();
    }

    public void push(BucketObject o) {
        s3ObjectStack.push(o);
    }

    public void printStack(){
        //Prints the contents of mObjects for each BucketObject in the stack.

        for(BucketObject o : s3ObjectStack){
            int i = 0;
            Log.i("BucketObject ", o.toString());
            for(BucketObject b : o.getmObjects()){
                Log.i("mObjects " + Integer.toString(i), b.toString());
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class to generate S3 objects.

```
public class S3ObjectSummary {
    private final String key;
    private static final String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    public S3ObjectSummary(){
        key = randomString(7);
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    private String randomString(int len){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            sb.append(abc.charAt(rnd.nextInt(abc.length())));
        }
        sb.insert(3, '/');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Main Activity class.

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }
}
```

The xml for the activity with fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ie.codemaker.test_panda.StartActivity">

    <fragment
        android:name="ie.codemaker.test_panda.BucketObjectListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: I've edited the above to provide a complete, minimal and verifiable program. This has helped me narrow the problem down to the `setData()` method of the adapter. Even if I rename the clicked object to something other than `o`, which is the first object on the stack, the first object's private field still changes at `setData()`. If anyone also needs the Manifest.xml to run the code I can provide it.

Comment: Show the declaration of `mObjects`.

Comment: Show your unit tests.

Comment: It's a bit strange that you're assigning it in `setHomeObjects()` and then again in `setmObjects()`.

Comment: @shmosel: declaration of mObjects added.

Comment: @Bob Dalgleish: Afraid I don't have any.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to solve the problem. Please try to include a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel: setmObjects is the called function. setHomeObjects is called by setmObjects only once soon after OnCreate is called to create the object for the home directory. This is not a clickable event. setNonHomeObjects is the function being called by setmObject on a clickable event.

Comment: @shmosel: method for setNonHomeObjects added.

Comment: Too much info and not enough info. Again, try to reduce the problem to a [mcve]. Also, `suffix != ""` is the wrong way to compare strings.

Comment: @shmosel: thanks for your comments. I really appreciate your help and suggestions. Unfortunately, it will be very difficult to post a complete example because of the size of the code and the need to have Amazon and Google API authentication keys to fully reproduce the results.

Comment: You missed the "minimal" part. Did you read the linked page?

Comment: @shmosel: Yes I read it. Minimal and complete - that's a challenge!

Comment: It is, but it often pays off by showing the problem in the process.

Comment: @shmosel: I'll try and meet the minimal and complete challenge.

Comment: @shmosel: (hopefully) a minimal, complete and verifiable program given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was, as someone else has pointed out in an answer to another question, "a typical Java error with pointers" using Android's ArrayAdapter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14408492/3350944

In the following line I'm passing the array `mObjects` to the adapter:

```
ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter(o.getmObjects());
```

Then, in this line I'm passing a new array `mObjects` to the adapter but the adapter is still pointing to the first array:

```
adapter.setData(p.getmObjects());
```

I solved the problem with a new arrayList<> in class BucketObjectListFragment which I passed to the adapter:

```
private ArrayList<BucketObject> newArray;
ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter(newArray);
```

Then when i want to update the adapter, I clear the adapter's list and add the items to `newArray` from `mObjects`:

```
viewList.clear();
for(BucketObject obj : p.getmObjects()){
    newArray.add(obj);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```